# Default value not set in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

can anyone see why "9:00" isn't selected in this select?

```
=f.fields_for :hours do |hours_form|
  = hours_form.text_field :start_time # outputs "9:00"

  =hours_form.select :start_time, possible_hours_stop() # outputs a select including one where value="9:00"
```

Shouldn't "9:00" be selected since that's the value of :start_time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
=hours_form.select :start_time, options_for_select(possible_hours_stop(), hours_form.object.start_time)
```